# Buckling Question from Hibbler Textbook

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

[image]

Hello! I have a question from the Hibbler Textbook on Mechanics of Materials! The exact statement of the problem reads:

> "A W150 * 24 steel column is 8 m long and is fixed at its ends as shown in Fig. 13–12a. Its load-carrying capacity is increased by bracing it about the y–y (weak) axis using struts that are assumed to be pin connected to its midheight. Determine the load it can support so that the column does not buckle nor the material exceed the yield stress. Take E = 200 GPa
> and Yield Stress = 410 MPa"

My question is: how did they determine the shape and the effective length for y-y axis buckling in the picture? There wasn't any explanation and I have no idea how they got that.

Any help would be much appreciated!